# Scar Divi Float or Double to Int

Tags: int, double, pascal

Scar Divi Float or Double to Int. How I pass a Float/Double to Integer?

Here's the code. I'm trying to Find the bitmap and click on the center, the problem is when I try to divide the x or y to find the img center.

```
program FindBitmap;

label
main;

var
Bmp: TSCARBitmap;
x, y: Integer;
temp1, temp2: String;

begin
 ClearDebug;
 Bmp := TSCARBitmap.Create('deNqtzGkKglAUhuE2Ea2pwXm8atpAFCIVRdEKi' +
    'qJCkBBpAeVQa+zCBRGH++cEz6/Dd95Oq92ajoZwE8eCG9sm3GhowDkWgrNNHc4' +
    'yNDgTqbnz6fjNMrr49XIXs+IXZuhK0fVyphSS99tz56UXDGlyEb7491ttIY3jp' +
    'eeW9oSuSCVIlQPfLxWyJFkvveqY0GSxCnceQZAXPmm6Xa9ql4QqCbVwJwpDEtl' +
    'vN00zQhb5JkhTnlF02O8oG0ISOApFEugDQuRZOIFj4Hh2AMcxfTh20PuDfhfuB' +
    '32bFT0=');
main:        
if FindBitmap (x, y, Bmp, 0, 0, 2559, 1023) then
begin
WriteLn('IMG FOUND!');    
ClickMouse((x + Bmp.Width / 2),(y + Bmp.Height / 2),mbLeft);
end
else
begin
goto main
end;

end.
```

ClickMouse doesn't work, Scar Divi says: Type mismatch

Comment: "the problem is..." - what happens? What do you want to happen?

Comment: Edit. Pass Double or Float to Integer.

Comment: `procedure ClickMouse(const X, Y: Integer; const Btn: TMouseButton);` requires a `const` for each of the parameters. You need to reformulate the way you think about your problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but if I do, use `div` instead of `/`, or Trunc, or anything that would return an integer. `ClickMouse((x + Bmp.Width div 2), ...`

Comment: How was `mbLeft` defined? Could that be the parameter that is causing a problem? A simple check could be to call `ClickMouse(100,100,mbLeft)` and see if that works. Perhaps we are looking in the wrong place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, tanks to all. **Sertac Akyuz** had the solution: change the / for a div to return an integer.

```
ClickMouse((x + Bmp.Width div 2),(y + Bmp.Height div 2),mbLeft);
```

The problem was that I can't have a decimal coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a datatype, you "cast" it (not "pass"). See [this link](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Type-Casts.html).

```
ClickMouse(Integer(x + Bmp.Width / 2),Integer(y + Bmp.Height / 2),mbLeft);
```

When I look at the [definition of ClickMouse](http://wiki.scar-divi.com/index.php?title=ClickMouseEx), it wants not just an `Integer`, it wants a `const Integer` for all its parameters:

```
 procedure ClickMouse(const X, Y: Integer; const Btn: TMouseButton);
```

By [definition](http://www.gnu-pascal.de/gpc/Constant-Declaration.html), a `const` has to be evaluatable at compilation time. If I understand that correctly, then the approach you are taking cannot work...

Comment: As I said - I suspect you're out of luck. It is not possible to make the data type be "const" if you have to compute it on the fly. Seems like a really bad design choice on the part of the people who made this library - but there it is. I don't think you can cast to `const`. So while I answered your question (about casting) it doesn't solve your problem (how to generate a mouseclick at a location that is not known at compile time). Sorry.

Comment: Thinking about this more - do you need to click in the middle of the bitmap? What is the context of your question? If you can click in a fixed location, you can use `ClickMouse(100,100,mbLeft);` - with whatever numbers you want.

Comment: A `const` declaration is different than a `const` parameter. Your link is irrelevant.

Comment: Sertac is right - "Specifying a parameter as Constant is giving the compiler a hint that the contents of the parameter will not be changed by the called routine. This allows the compiler to perform optimizations which it could not do otherwise, and also to perform certain checks on the code inside the routine: namely, it can forbid assignments to the parameter. " I was confusing my Pascal and C.